# Cannot locate the element include "anchor" using Nightwatch (Selenium2)

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

As the title mentioned, I use Nightwatch to do some browser-action tests. However, whenever I need to locate the element using id within "anchor", failure always happened. 
For example:

```
<span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinnerAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div></span>
```

This is the element I want to find, so

> .click("#recaptcha-anchor")
>   is used, but that doesn't work.

Another example is:

```
<a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="6_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon ace-icon fa fa-circle-thin green jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>Test</a>
```

Same things just happened.

Comment: So i guess basically you want to invoke a programmatic click on that elemen, right?

Comment: Can you show the other nightwatch.js code (that clicks the a element)?  Also you can precede the "#" with span, (span#recaptcha-anchor) - lastly, if you have control over the HTML, I would not nest div tags (block elements) inside of <span> which are inline elements.

Comment: At last I discovered that the first example is a Google recaptcha component. So maybe being invisible is the property.

Comment: However the other component I still cannot figure out why nightwatch never see it. I use chrome to get the css and it gives me "#\36 _anchor".
What does that "\3" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector seems good,
but before invoke click check the presence of the element:

```
'Your Test' : function (browser) {
    browser
        .waitForElementPresent('#recaptcha-anchor', 1000)
        .click('#recaptcha-anchor')
        .end()
    ;
}
```

And if you use an old version of NightWatch, maybe you should use this function to force CSS selector :

```
browser.useCss().click('#recaptcha-anchor')
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that way before. However the component couldn't be caught either.

Comment: ok... 
Can you share the full source code of your test case ?

Comment: Finally I realize that what recaptcha tries to do is to stop robot such as my test case from entering the website. Thanks for your help anyway! However, I still have another test case that I cannot figure out. Below is the link of my test case code and the part of website.

Comment: `<a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="7278_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon ace-icon fa fa-circle-thin green jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>test</a>`

using this code
**.click("#\37 278_anchor")**

Answer (score 0):

I can not see the anchor tag in first given code in question.
But for the code that you have given in comment , I have just noticed , your CSS id is starting with a number, According to convention ID should not start with a number, May be this is the reason Nightwatch is also not handling ID starting with number, Try removing the number from ID and then try to click

```html
<a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon ace-icon fa fa-circle-thin green jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>test</a>
```

```
.click("#anchor")
```

Hope it may help you.